# Not all code paths do return a value - what is wrong?

Tags: c#

I have made a function that in my opinion will always return a value, but the function still says

> All code paths does not return a value

Am I missing something?

```
public static bool CheckIfSignatureAlreadySignedByUser(SPSite site, SPWeb web, int RowID)
{
    RevertToAppPool revert = new RevertToAppPool();

    try
    {
        revert.UseAppPoolIdentity();
        string dbConnectionString = site.WebApplication.Properties["dbConnection"].ToString();
        using (dbDWDataContext dataContext = new dbDWDataContext(dbConnectionString))
        {
            var signatures = dataContext.CM_Signatures.Where(c => c.ParagraphID == RowID).ToList();
            if (signatures.Any())
            {
                foreach (var sig in signatures)
                {
                    if (sig.LoginName.ToLower() == web.CurrentUser.LoginName.ToLower())
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                    else
                        return true;
                }    
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }                                    
        }
    }
    catch (Exception error)
    {
        SEPUtilities.WriteErrorToLog("Error in DWUtilities.AddSignature: {0}", error.ToString());
        return false;
    }
    finally
    {
        revert.ReturnToImpersonatingCurrentUser();
    }
}
```

Comment: you use `foreach` and then `if else` that both return from method? your foreach is useless i think. it doesnt make sense because it will always return from first iteration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Patrick Hofman has the right answer.

That said, I would refactor:

```
if (signatures != null && signatures.Any())
{
    foreach (var sig in signatures)
    {
        if (sig.LoginName.ToLower() == web.CurrentUser.LoginName.ToLower())
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
            return true;
    }    
}
else
{
    return true;
}
```

to:

```
return !signatures.Any(z => z.LoginName.ToLower() == web.CurrentUser.LoginName.ToLower());
```

Comment: I agree with the refactoring, but note that it does NOT do the same as the original code! This would only be a correct refactoring if you are correcting a bug in the OP's code.

Comment: @MatthewWatson True, but I assumed the OP's code was buggy: the `Where` clause that was written should only return _one_ element (or the code was _really_ wrong: no `OrderBy` and _then_ an enumeration that only takes the first element (which one? dunno as there is no order) into account...), so it should be equivalent.

Comment: Yep, I also think the OP's code has a bug. Seems that some random downvoter disagrees, so he's downvoted my answer (but seems to think your's is OK ;) Anyway, have an upvote.

Answer (score 9):

The compiler doesn't know that `signatures` always will yield at least one result, since you checked it before:

```
if (signatures.Any())
{
    foreach (var sig in signatures)
    { ... }

    // problem here.
```

What it wants you to do is `return` anything after your `foreach` statement. (And for what it is worth, `signatures` *can* change between the `Any` and `foreach` statements due to another thread modifying it).

Comment: But can `signatures`, realistically, be changed? It's a function-scoped instance, not a member variable, that isn't returned out of scope. Perhaps the static analyzer can't 100% determine that?

Comment: Indeed, but what if `Any` starts a thread, modifying it in the background? The compiler doesn't know all this.

Comment: You're right. It *is* passed out of scope - to the `Any` extension method. Good call. `Any` could, theoretically, even without threads, return *true* while cleaning out the list.

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan Furthermore, the instance is actually not function-scoped, only the variable is. The instance is instantiated elsewhere and only a reference is obtained via the external calls to `Where` and `ToList`, and so there may well be other references to it.

Answer (score 1):

Others have already answered, but here's some additional information.

I think that your loop is incorrect:

```
var signatures = dataContext.CM_Signatures.Where(c => c.ParagraphID == RowID).ToList();
if (signatures.Any())
{
    foreach (var sig in signatures)
    {
        if (sig.LoginName.ToLower() == web.CurrentUser.LoginName.ToLower())
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
            return true;
    }    
}
else
{
    return true;
}
```

The `foreach` loop will only iterate once. If you are trying to find out if no signature matches the current user, then this will fail if the first signature does match, even if a later one doesn't match, because the `return false` will terminate the loop early.

Perhaps you really mean to do this:

```
return !signatures.Any(sig => 
    string.Compare(sig.LoginName, web.CurrentUser.LoginName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0);
```

Comment: @downvoter: Can you explain what you think is wrong? And if there is something wrong, then Ken2K's answer is also wrong (but you didn't downvote that). I'm thinking that you are likely missing something...

Comment: Doesn't deserve a downvote at all. So here's my +1 to balance :)

Comment: @downvoter And now we see that you are indeed missing something, since the OP has marked Ken's answer as the correct one. :) (and thanks Ken ;)

Answer (score 0):

I guess the branch analysis for if-foreach { if-else } fails because VS does not now that signatures.Any will not enter the if. Instead try to write

```
public static bool CheckIfSignatureAlreadySignedByUser(SPSite site, SPWeb web, int RowID)
    {
        RevertToAppPool revert = new RevertToAppPool();

        try
        {
            revert.UseAppPoolIdentity();
            string dbConnectionString = site.WebApplication.Properties["dbConnection"].ToString();
            using (dbDWDataContext dataContext = new dbDWDataContext(dbConnectionString))
            {
                var signatures = dataContext.CM_Signatures.Where(c => c.ParagraphID == RowID).ToList();
                if (signatures != null && signatures.Any())
                {
                    foreach (var sig in signatures)
                    {
                        if (sig.LoginName.ToLower() == web.CurrentUser.LoginName.ToLower())
                        {
                            return false;
                        }
                        else
                            return true;
                    }

                }

                return true;                    
            }
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            SEPUtilities.WriteErrorToLog("Error in DWUtilities.AddSignature: {0}", error.ToString());
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            revert.ReturnToImpersonatingCurrentUser();
        }

    }
```